# Authentication in IIS and classic ASP

Tags: authentication, iis, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP web application (not ASP.NET).

The application has it's own authentication mechanism, handled in asp files. The problem is, the authentication is triggered only when an asp file is requested. I want it to trigger when any (static file) is requested as well (e.g. there are pdfs stored in some directories and I would like to make them available only to logged in users). The same for static HTML pages.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: This is depends on which mechanism You use. Please explain, how your authentication mechanism work.

Comment: One way you can do this through Classic ASP is to write an impersonation routine in an external app like VB6 or ASP.NET to do the actual impersonating for you.  [This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248187) discusses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map the PDF file to aspnet_isapi.dll in IIS.

You can then use Forms authentication which is a part of ASP.NET and comes outside the box.

If you don't want to use .NET at all, you can write an ISAPI filter or extension that can handle this for you.

Comment: The OP's not using ASP.NET - it's Classic ASP.

Comment: Yes, the website now runs classic ASP, not ASP.NET

Comment: Writing a custom ISAPI filter might be an option, but I must admit I was hoping for some simpler solution.

Comment: I understand that you are running ASP.NET. My recommendation is to use ASP.NET's form based authentication ONLY for the PDF file. Rest of your application can continue to work with ASP. Is more about using aspnet_isapi extension, rather than creating your own from scratch.